# Private static methods. Generally good idea?

Tags: c#, oop, types

The following extract is from an FX Cop warning.

> Methods that do not access instance data or call instance methods can
>   be marked as static (Shared in Visual Basic). After you mark the
>   methods as static, the compiler will emit non-virtual call sites to
>   these members. Emitting non-virtual call sites will prevent a check at
>   runtime for each call that ensures that the current object pointer is
>   non-null. This can result in a measurable performance gain for
>   performance-sensitive code. In some cases, the failure to access the
>   current object instance represents a correctness issue.

I understand the performance benefits of making private methods static if they don't access instance data or methods but I'm not sure that in most cases the above advice is good. If you're writing extremely performance critical code, and you've got no choice then to write it in c#, I can understand the sentiment but considering that generally, robust, easier to read, and easy to refactor code is preferred over performance should you actually follow this advice?

The problem I have with private static methods this that when you need to refactor a class I find that static methods make it more difficult to do so. If you have a large number of static methods, and you need to change one to use an instance variable, and that method is used by other private static methods, you end up having to make more changes in order to get this working. Below is an example (please bear in mind this is an minimal implementation just to demonstrate the point):

```
public class Test
    {
        private IService myService;

        private static void DoSomething()
        {
            DoSomethingElse();
        }

        private static void DoSomethingElse()
        {
            DoSomethingMore();
        }

        private static void DoSomethingMore()
        {
            Console.Write("DO SOMETHING");
        }
    }
```

If I want to use `myService` in the DoSomethingMore method, it means I have to make not only that method non-static, but the previous two methods as well. This seems burdensome.

What are other peoples thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm in agreement - it's a lot easier to refactor code from non-static -> static than the other way round, that's why I only make things static if it makes **really** good sense to me.

Comment: modifying working code just to get (unneeded and unperceived) performance is what I call premature optimization.

Comment: Static methods are normally easier to refactor as they most likely do not change any state and they are functional in nature. I use them liberally in code I write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This seems burdensome.

When you consider that the *entire chain of function calls* becomes dependent upon an instance when you modify your `DoSomethingMore` method, the feeling of the changes being "burdensome" should become "necessary" instead.

What you should first consider are the semantics of the methods you're writing. When you write a method, you need to ask yourself whether the code should be an instance method (because it should semantically be an action associated with a single instance) or a static method (for anything else) and that decision should drive how you write the method.

Until you have **measured** performance shortcomings that are unacceptable in production code, you should make the method instance or static depending on what makes sense for your domain, not anything else.

Comment: I think your answer is in line with David M. Kean's comment on the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms245046(v=vs.80).aspx) for this warning. *Although this rule is classified as a performance issue, the performance improvement of making a method static is only around 1%.
Rather, it is more a correctness issue that could indicate an either an incomplete or a bug in the member by its failure to use other instance members. Marking a method static (Shared in Visual Basic) makes it clear on its intention not to touch instance state.*